# How to compute higher ramification groups?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification, cyclotomic-fields

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of number fields with Galois group $G$. Let $O_K$ and $O_L$ be the ring of algebraic integers of $K$ and $L$ respectively. Let $P\subseteq O_K$ be a prime. Let $Q\subseteq O_L$ be a prime lying over $P$.

The decomposition group is defined as $$D(Q|P)=\lbrace \sigma\in G\text{ }|\text{ }\sigma(Q)=Q\rbrace$$

The $n$-th ramification group is defined as  $$E_n(Q|P)=\lbrace \sigma\in G:\sigma(a)\equiv a\text{ mod } Q^{n+1}\text{ for all } a\in O_L\rbrace$$

I want to compute the decomposition group and ramification groups of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity ($p$ is a prime).

In general, how to calculate it for an arbitrary cyclotomic field ?

Comment: Do you want to compute the decomposition group and ramification groups of a prime ideal of the cyclotomic field $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$? For instance a prime ideal over the integer prime $p$? You question isn't clear otherwise (in my opinion).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Since $p$ is totally ramified in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$, it follows that $D(P|p) = \mathrm{Gal}(K/\Bbb Q) =: G$ where $P$ is a prime ideal of $\mathcal O_K$ above $p$ and $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta_p)$, since the order of $D(P)$ is $e_{P \mid p} \cdot f_{P \mid p}$.

Comment: What about the ramification groups ?

Comment: You know that $\sigma(\zeta_p) = \zeta_p^k$ for some $k$ coprime with $p$. Then try to see when $\zeta_p^k -\zeta_p \in (1-\zeta_p)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279264/

Comment: See also http://wstein.org/wiki/attachments/ant07(2f)projects/ooka.pdf.

Comment: See Sublemma 1 in An Elementary Proof of the Kronecker-Weber Theorem by M. J. Greenberg : if $K/\Bbb Q$ is abelian of degree $p$ (odd prime number), such that $p$ is the only ramified prime, then the second ramification group $E_2(P/p)$ is trivial (for any $P$ over $p$).

Comment: Moreover, we can localize at $P$, so that we can assume that $P$ is principal (then you just have to check $\sigma(a) \equiv a \pmod{Q^{n+1}}$ for the uniformizer $a$ (and maybe $\sigma \in E_{n-1}$), to conclude that $\sigma \in E_n$).